# Guava Collection Utils vs. plain Java 7

Tags: java, collections, guava

I am often tempted to write code using Guava's collection utils and find myself rewriting the code in plain Java 7 after looking at the code fragment, because it IMHO turns out to be more concise and easier to read using plain old Java.

For instance putting a list of objects into a map with a unique index taken from the objects would look something like this using Guava:

```
 List<A> myList = ...
 Map<A, B> mappings = Maps.uniqueIndex(myList, new Function<A, B>() {
     @Override
     public CustomerFinance apply(final A input) {
         return input.getB();
     }
 });
```

whereas in vanilla Java 7 it would be:

```
List<A> myList = ...
Map<A, B> mappings = new HashMap<>(myList.size());
for (A a : myList) {
    mappings.put(a.getB(), a);
}
```

That's 5 LOC's for the mapping in Guava (even not counting the `@Override` line) versus 4 LOC's in plain Java.

Why should I use the Guava utils here? What was the incentive in creating the utils in the first place? Am I missing some added benefit that Guava will provide me?

Comment: Java 8 has been out for well over 2 years, and it can do the task in 1 line. Why do you care about Java 7?

Comment: I seriously don't and I would like to upgrade rather sooner than later. Unfortunately important stake holders involved with the current project I'm working on disagree.

Comment: Your Java 7 is only shorter, because it is a incomplete "translation" of the Guava code. Guavas resulting Map is immutable and doesn't allow `null` as one of the values. Your code completely ignores that.

Comment: @Tom Immutability is an issue, yes. But in my actual use case I even needed a *mutable* map. So the Guava version was even longer, because I had to feed the resulting map into a HashMap to get a mutable version.

Comment: @Tom: Thank's for point with the `null` values: I don't have to handle `null` keys in my actual use case, but you certainly got me thinking in the right way: Guava will not only check for `null` values but `uniqueIndex` will also fail fast, if a key is found twice. Which actually *is* a benefit in my case. I would happily accept this as the correct answer, if you submit this as an answer.

Comment: @all downvoters: Sometimes I don't get it with you guys on SO. What's the problem with this question? Could you explain?

Comment: FWIW, Guava [doesn't recommend](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained#caveats) going out of your way to use its functional idioms in Java 7 if the alternative is more concise. They're more useful when the the function is something you might want to reuse (or you can use one of the functions Guava provides) or when the operation itself is complex enough that writing it yourself is error-prone or makes your code more complex.

Comment: @Bohemian I'd love to use Java 8 for Android development, for example.  However, it is not as feasible as Java 7 for several reasons.

Comment: @Igor the question isn't tagged with andriod

Comment: @Bohemian Android is Java, and as such is relevant from a Java developer's perspective.  I'd like to use your suggestion above, but cannot due to said issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing some added benefit that Guava will provide me?

Yes you do.

There are several features in Guava which your translated code misses ([JavaDoc of Maps#uniqueIndex](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29)):

- `null` for values is prohibited (#)
- `null` for keys is prohibited (the key function shouldn't return `null` for a given value)
- duplicate keys are prohibited (you can't unexpectedly overwrite existing keys)
- the resulting map is *immutable*

If you would all these checks as well, then your code should be a longer than Guavas version.

(#) Mind, that your translated version currently prohibits `null` as well, because you call `#getB()` on your value object. This will cause a `NullPointerException` like in Guava. If you would get the key from somewhere else like in `mappings.put(generateArtificalKey(), a);`, then `null` would be fine for the Java 7 version.

---

Another advantage is the cleaner code of the key function. It can be easily moved into an own class and be reused. An example for that might be a function which extracts the id of database entities to create a map with that. But this is a more an opinion, than a fact since your translated code (the `for` loop) can also be extracted and used for other cases.

Comment: Actually, your statement about `null` is not correct: The vanilla version will NOT throw an NPE, if `a.getB()` returns `null`, whereas the Guava version will.

Comment: @StefanHaberl Your version will throw the NPE, because if `a` is `null`, then `a.getB()` won't work. If you won't call something on `a` and use something else as the key, then _yes_ the vanilla version won't throw the NPE. But I used your version as the reference. That is why I moved that point to the bottom (I had it in the list first). I hope my answer is a bit clearer, now.

Comment: Sure, but if `a != null` and `a.getB() == null`, the vanilla version will work, whereas the Guava version will throw a NPE :D

Comment: @StefanHaberl But your code doesn't check for `null` like that ;P.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Your sentence *"that both versions prohibit null for a value"* refers to `null` as a value **of the resulting map**, whereas I misread it as `null` as outcome of the calculation of the key value. My bad.

Comment: @StefanHaberl That sentence means, that your version only prohibits `null`, because you have no `null` check for `a` and `a#getB()` will cause the NPE. If this wouldn't be the case, then "vanilla" will be fine with `null` :).

Comment: Totally agree and to state it explicitly: The vanilla version prohibits `null` as resulting values, but allows `null` as resulting keys, whereas Guava will prevent `null` values and `null`keys.

Answer (score 2):

You might argue that yes, there is not a big gain in terms of LOC's. However, the Guava style is more `functional`.

The transform function can be passed around and used/reused.

```
 Function<A,B> map = new Function<A, B>() {
 @Override
 public CustomerFinance apply(final A input) {
     return input.getB();
 }
```

Now you can pass map around and reuse it not different places.

```
Map<A, B> mappings = Maps.uniqueIndex(myList,map);
Map<C, D> mappings2 = Maps.uniqueIndex(myList,map);
```

But then again, `Guava` is limited to Java 1.6 constructs, which doesn't give the best experience for declarative style.

The good news is that `Function` in Guava is a `functional interface`, so if you move to Java 1.8, you can start using lambdas from day one, and your code will look like this,

```
Map<A, B> mappings = Maps.uniqueIndex(myList, input-> input.getB());
```

Or

```
Map<A, B> mappings = Maps.uniqueIndex(myList, A::getB);
```

Comment: I'm aware that I could use lambda's in Java 8. For the current project, however, I'm stuck with Java 7. My original concern is how far I should go down the "functional" road with Java 7. If I don't share or reuse the function, you're basically saying it's a matter of taste (or simply a more "fashionable" approach)?

Comment: @StefanHaberl I don't think there is something in my answer that could be read as "fashionable". I showed you some examples to demonstrate the benefits and conciseness.

Comment: Agreed. So the benefit in conciseness is when I start sharing my function. Which I don't. Upgrading to Java 8 is (unfortunately) not an option. So there's no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

When I program in versions of Java older than 8, I usually create an associated utility class, named as the entity but in plural form, and add all the utility method to it. This way, I keep my entities clean and I have access to a large panel of utility methods. I don't systematically create a utility class, but only when needed to reduce noise.

```
public class MyEntity {
  private String text;
  public String getText() { return text; }
  public void setText (int text) { this.text = text; }
}

public final class MyEntities {
  private MyEntities() {}

  private enum MyEntityToString implements Function<MyEntity,String> {
    TEXT_GETTER {
      @Override public String apply(MyEntity input) { return input.getText(); }
    };
  }
  public static Function<MyEntity,String> textGetter() { return MyEntityToString.TEXT_GETTER; }
}
```

Then, the usage becomes as simple as using the method `MyEntities.textGetter()` when needed. If you use it only once, yes, you lose in terms of LOCs, but if you use it several times, you just win. Also, if you ever have a bug, you have to fix it only once and not find every usage to fix it everywhere.

Comment: I totally agree. DRY. I'm doing exactly the same thing when I need the exact code fragment twice (mostly with Predicates, though). But more often than not, I have code which is specific to just one use case. And then I don't want to externalize the logic into a separate function, which IMHO is harder to read (again, when I've to stick to Java 7)

Comment: If it's specific to one use case, you can write the function in a different place of the class using it. It's still easier to read. Then move it to a utility class if more use cases show up.